# PopUp in React.js with a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blockchain, solidity

I want make a popup which include a link . I want do it when the a button pressed. Can I add two onclick event? and if yes how?(LoL you're mean like instagram. i won't ever ask a joke question again).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two onClick events, just make a function that do both things, or make two functions and call it in the onClick handler